# How to perform "INNER JOIN" of powershell objects?

Tags: powershell, storage, reliability

I am trying to query for various physical disk health information.

I have two queries that each return separate information about **PhysicalDisk**s.

```
>Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceId, FriendlyName, Model, SerialNumber, Usage, HealthStatus, CanPool, CannotPoolReason | Format-Table
```

| DeviceId | Model | SerialNumber | FriendlyName | Usage | HealthStatus | CanPool | CannotPoolReason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | VGJKAJEG | ATA WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | Auto-Select | Healthy | False | In a Pool |
| 1 | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K6NE2J5J | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | Auto-Select | Healthy | True |  |
| 2 | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K5RYNVZD | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | Hot Spare | Healthy | False | In a Pool |
| 3 | WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | VGGDU8GG | ATA WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | Auto-Select | Healthy | False | In a Pool |
| 4 | WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | VGKE7HJG | ATA WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | Auto-Select | Healthy | False | In a Pool |
| 5 | Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB | 0025_385A_9150_212F. | Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB | Auto-Select | Healthy | True |  |
| 6 | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K5KP57ZJ | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | Hot Spare | Healthy | False | In a Pool |
| 7 | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K1URKJV5 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | Hot Spare | Healthy | False | In a Pool |
| 8 | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K1TZUVDD | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | Auto-Select | Healthy | False | In a Pool |
| 9 | Elements 25A3 | 2SGDZYXJ | WD Elements 25A3 | Auto-Select | Healthy | False | Insufficient Capacity |
| 10 | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K6HJV122 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | Auto-Select | Healthy | False | In a Pool |
| 11 | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K1PHSSE7 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | Auto-Select | Healthy | False | In a Pool |
| 12 | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K5XL728J | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | Auto-Select | Healthy | False | In a Pool |
| 13 | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K3DNAYHT | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | Auto-Select | Healthy | False | In a Pool |

And then there's the SMART attributes of the same physical disks:

```
>Get-PhysicalDisk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Select-Object Number, DeviceId, PowerOnHours, ReadErrorsTotal, Temperature, ReadLatencyMax, WriteLatencyMax | Format-Table
```

| DeviceId | PowerOnHours | ReadErrorsTotal | Temperature | ReadLatencyMax | WriteLatencyMax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 40340 | 0 | 28 | 155 | 283 |
| 6 | 25774 | 0 | 29 | 712 | 226 |
| 8 | 17383 | 0 | 29 | 190 | 163 |
| 12 |  |  | 36 | 489 | 287 |
| 13 | 1486 | 0 | 31 | 19376 | 0 |
| 5 | 25781 | 0 | 31 | 699 | 208 |
| 0 | 28385 | 0 | 27 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 35341 | 0 | 28 | 197 | 168 |
| 3 | 41524 | 0 | 27 | 177 | 193 |
| 11 | 13743 | 0 | 38 | 242 | 148 |
| 2 | 33553 | 0 | 28 | 365 | 422 |
| 10 | 14000 | 0 | 34 | 239 | 418 |
| 9 | 14000 | 0 | 36 | 234 | 368 |
| 7 | 25746 | 0 | 28 | 4 |  |

Well now i want these merged into single-rows:

| DeviceId | FriendlyName | Model | SerialNumber | Usage | HealthStatus | CanPool | CannotPoolReason | PowerOnHours | ReadErrorsTotal | Temperature | ReadLatencyMax | WriteLatencyMax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K6NE2J5J | Auto-Select | Healthy | TRUE |  | 28385 | 0 | 27 | 1 |  |
| 1 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K1TZUVDD | Auto-Select | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 35341 | 0 | 28 | 197 | 168 |
| 2 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K6HJV122 | Auto-Select | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 33553 | 0 | 28 | 365 | 422 |
| 3 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K5KP57ZJ | Hot Spare | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 41524 | 0 | 27 | 177 | 193 |
| 4 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K1URKJV5 | Hot Spare | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 40340 | 0 | 28 | 155 | 283 |
| 5 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K3DNAYHT | Auto-Select | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 25781 | 0 | 31 | 699 | 208 |
| 6 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K1PHSSE7 | Auto-Select | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 25774 | 0 | 29 | 712 | 226 |
| 7 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K5RYNVZD | Hot Spare | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 25746 | 0 | 28 | 4 |  |
| 8 | ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WDC WD40EFRX-68N | WD-WCC7K5XL728J | Auto-Select | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 17383 | 0 | 29 | 190 | 163 |
| 9 | ATA WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | VGGDU8GG | Auto-Select | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 14000 | 0 | 36 | 234 | 368 |
| 10 | ATA WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | VGJKAJEG | Auto-Select | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 14000 | 0 | 34 | 239 | 418 |
| 11 | ATA WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | WDC WD80EDAZ-11T | VGKE7HJG | Auto-Select | Healthy | FALSE | In a Pool | 13743 | 0 | 38 | 242 | 148 |
| 12 | Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB | Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB | 0025_385A_9150_212F. | Auto-Select | Healthy | TRUE |  |  |  | 36 | 489 | 287 |
| 13 | WD Elements 25A3 | Elements 25A3 | 2SGDZYXJ | Auto-Select | Healthy | FALSE | Insufficient Capacity | 1486 | 0 | 31 | 19376 | 0 |

In SQL Server relational databases that would be an `INNER JOIN` on **DeviceId**.

How can i combine these two results set into one set?

Comment: Related at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575638/how-to-join-two-object-arrays-in-powershell

Comment: DeviceID is missing on the first table. Can you add it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848821/in-powershell-whats-the-best-way-to-join-two-tables-into-one

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Join-Object](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join-Object/2.0.3) module to accomplish the task

> Join data from two sets of objects based on a common value.

- Install Join-Object module

```ps
Install-Module -Name Join-Object
```

- Create the two lists

```
$FirstList = Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID, FriendlyName, Model, SerialNumber, Usage, HealthStatus, CanPool, CannotPoolReason
$SecondList = Get-PhysicalDisk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Select-Object Number, DeviceId, PowerOnHours, ReadErrorsTotal, Temperature, ReadLatencyMax, WriteLatencyMax
```

- Join the lists using Join-Object

```ps
$JoinedResult = Join-Object -left $FirstList -Right $SecondList -LeftJoinProperty DeviceID -RightJoinProperty DeviceID -KeepRightJoinProperty -Type OnlyIfInBoth -Prefix r_

$JoinedResult | Select DeviceID, FriendlyName, Model, SerialNumber, Usage, HealthStatus, CanPool, CannotPoolReason, r_PowerOnHours,r_ReadErrorsTotal, r_Temperature, r_ReadLatencyMax, r_WriteLatencyMax
```

From [Connect data with PowerShell's Join-Object module](https://www.techtarget.com/searchitoperations/tutorial/Connect-data-with-PowerShells-Join-Object-module), here is an explanation of Join-Object's parameters (replace where mentioned: $process with $FirstList, $services with $Secondlist, name with DevideID and *service with r*)

> 1. We have --Left and --Right. These are simply the objects we want to join, which are $processes and $services as defined above.
> 2. We use the --LeftJoinProperty and --RightJoinProperty commands. This is the property from these two objects we want to join together. In this case, they have the same name, which is "name."
> 3. The next parameter, --KeepRightJoinProperty includes the right joined property in the output of the join operation. I will demonstrate this further along in this tutorial.
> 4. The --Type parameter is important, because this is where you specify what type of join you would like to perform. I used OnlyIfInBoth to see any processes and services with the same name.
>
> The other options taken directly from the PowerShell help are as follows:
>
> - AllInLeft. This is the default parameter, which displays all Left elements in the output present at least once, depending on how many elements apply in Right.
> - AllInRight. This is similar to AllInLeft.
> - OnlyIfInBoth. Places all elements from Left in the output, regardless of how many matches are found in Right.
> - AllInBoth. Includes all entries in both Right and Left in output.
>
> 5. The last parameter is --Prefix. This is used to prefix each Right property in the join with whatever string you decide. In this case, I used _service.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do the normal PowerShell way, no additional stuff is needed.
Just normal pipeline stuff, with calculated properties. Well, one could have used a hash table or PSCustomObject as well.

```
Clear-Host
Get-PhysicalDisk | 
ForEach-Object {
    ($RecordData = $PSItem) | 
    Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | 
    Select-Object -Property @{
                                Name       = 'DeviceId'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.DeviceId}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'FriendlyName'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.FriendlyName}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'Model'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.Model}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'SerialNumber'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.SerialNumber}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'Usage'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.Usage}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'HealthStatus'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.HealthStatus}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'CanPool'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.CanPool}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'CannotPoolReason'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.CannotPoolReason}
                            },
                            Number, PowerOnHours, ReadErrorsTotal, 
                            Temperature, ReadLatencyMax, WriteLatencyMax
}
# Results
<#
...

DeviceId         : 1
FriendlyName     : Samsung SSD 950 PRO 512GB
Model            : Samsung SSD 950 PRO 512GB
SerialNumber     : 0000_0000_0000_0000
Usage            : Auto-Select
HealthStatus     : Healthy
CanPool          : False
CannotPoolReason : Insufficient Capacity
Number           : 
PowerOnHours     : 
ReadErrorsTotal  : 
Temperature      : 34
ReadLatencyMax   : 252
WriteLatencyMax  : 70
...
#>

Clear-Host
Get-PhysicalDisk | 
ForEach-Object {
    ($RecordData = $PSItem) | 
    Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | 
    Select-Object -Property @{
                                Name       = 'DeviceId'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.DeviceId}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'FriendlyName'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.FriendlyName}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'Model'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.Model}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'SerialNumber'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.SerialNumber}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'Usage'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.Usage}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'HealthStatus'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.HealthStatus}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'CanPool'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.CanPool}
                            }, 
                            @{
                                Name       = 'CannotPoolReason'
                                Expression = {$RecordData.CannotPoolReason}
                            },
                            Number, PowerOnHours, ReadErrorsTotal, 
                            Temperature, ReadLatencyMax, WriteLatencyMax
} | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
DeviceId FriendlyName              Model                     SerialNumber         Usage       HealthStatus CanPool CannotPoolReason      Number PowerOnHours
-------- ------------              -----                     ------------         -----       ------------ ------- ----------------      ------ ------------
...
1        Samsung SSD 950 PRO 512GB Samsung SSD 950 PRO 512GB 0000_0000_0000_0000. Auto-Select Healthy        False Insufficient Capacity                    
...                    
#>
```

Comment: Why not do it the normal powershell way? Because i don't know what the normal powershell way is!  If i did i wouldn't have had to ask the question. And everyone seems to love to link to a 3rd party cmdlet - which entirely defeats the point of the question.

Comment: All of us here are just trying to help you out. ***Nowhere in your post do you say implicitly/explicitly that 3rdP modules*** **(even the ones from the Microsoft powershellgallery.com - directly accessible from any PowerShell shell/editor)** ***are, not an option.*** So, quoting my inner ['Pet Detective'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tJGk4ofc18), but the 3rdP stuff notwithstanding, which addresses your use case in the context of your goal? All things being considered, are you saying, no response yet, meets your goal?

Comment: Lastly, what I show, is in the PowerShell help files as well. So, F1 or ```Get-Help -Name SomeCmdletName/SomeFunctionName -Examples``` or ```Get-Help -Name SomeCmdletName -Detail``` or the online MS PowerShell docs, would have allowed you to decern the same approach/result.

Comment: One more item as to the 3rdP stuff. Know that the moment you move to Microsoft Powershell Core (PowerShellv7 and beyond pwsh.exe), it is all open-sourced, so. all is MS and 3rdP contributes and maintain it all.

Answer (score 0):

Easily joining two object lists in PowerShell is a decennia old requirement (see e.g.: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/join-object/). Personally, I think that this should be an intuitive idiomatic PowerShell syntax. Unfortunately there is (still) no native PowerShell command that can do this which resulted in a sprawl of custom made `Join-Object` implementations.
Anyways, this is my implementation of a [`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule)
see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)

```
Install-Module -Name JoinModule

# $Disks = Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceId, FriendlyName, Model, SerialNumber, Usage, HealthStatus, CanPool, CannotPoolReason
$Disk = Read-HtmlTable https://superuser.com/q/1759239/1085094 -Table 0 # Install-Script -Name Read-HtmlTable

# Intialy, there was no DeviceID in the disk list where you might simply add it:
# $Disk = 0..13 |Join $Disk -Name DeviceId

# $Storage = Get-PhysicalDisk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Select-Object Number, DeviceId, PowerOnHours, ReadErrorsTotal, Temperature, ReadLatencyMax, WriteLatencyMax
$Storage = Read-HtmlTable https://superuser.com/q/1759239/1085094 -Table 1

$Disk |Join $Storage -on DeviceId |Format-Table *

DeviceId Model                     SerialNumber         FriendlyName              Usage       HealthStatus CanPool CannotPoolReason      PowerOnHours ReadErrorsTotal Temperature ReadLatencyMax WriteLatencyMax
-------- -----                     ------------         ------------              -----       ------------ ------- ----------------      ------------ --------------- ----------- -------------- ---------------
       0 WDC WD80EDAZ-11T          VGJKAJEG             ATA WDC WD80EDAZ-11T      Auto-Select Healthy      False   In a Pool             28385        0               27          1
       1 WDC WD40EFRX-68N          WD-WCC7K6NE2J5J      ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N      Auto-Select Healthy      True                          35341        0               28          197            168
       2 WDC WD40EFRX-68N          WD-WCC7K5RYNVZD      ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N      Hot Spare   Healthy      False   In a Pool             33553        0               28          365            422
       3 WDC WD80EDAZ-11T          VGGDU8GG             ATA WDC WD80EDAZ-11T      Auto-Select Healthy      False   In a Pool             41524        0               27          177            193
       4 WDC WD80EDAZ-11T          VGKE7HJG             ATA WDC WD80EDAZ-11T      Auto-Select Healthy      False   In a Pool             40340        0               28          155            283
       5 Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB 0025_385A_9150_212F. Samsung SSD 970 EVO 500GB Auto-Select Healthy      True                          25781        0               31          699            208
       6 WDC WD40EFRX-68N          WD-WCC7K5KP57ZJ      ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N      Hot Spare   Healthy      False   In a Pool             25774        0               29          712            226
       7 WDC WD40EFRX-68N          WD-WCC7K1URKJV5      ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N      Hot Spare   Healthy      False   In a Pool             25746        0               28          4
       8 WDC WD40EFRX-68N          WD-WCC7K1TZUVDD      ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N      Auto-Select Healthy      False   In a Pool             17383        0               29          190            163
       9 Elements 25A3             2SGDZYXJ             WD Elements 25A3          Auto-Select Healthy      False   Insufficient Capacity 14000        0               36          234            368
      10 WDC WD40EFRX-68N          WD-WCC7K6HJV122      ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N      Auto-Select Healthy      False   In a Pool             14000        0               34          239            418
      11 WDC WD40EFRX-68N          WD-WCC7K1PHSSE7      ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N      Auto-Select Healthy      False   In a Pool             13743        0               38          242            148
      12 WDC WD40EFRX-68N          WD-WCC7K5XL728J      ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N      Auto-Select Healthy      False   In a Pool                                          36          489            287
      13 WDC WD40EFRX-68N          WD-WCC7K3DNAYHT      ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N      Auto-Select Healthy      False   In a Pool             1486         0               31          19376          0
```

<sub>Please give a  if you support the proposal to [Add a Join-Object cmdlet to the standard PowerShell equipment (`#14994`)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14994)</sub>